# Issue with .mdf and installshield

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield, sql-server-2014, localdb

I have a program that connects to `.mdf` using SQL Server 2014 localdb. It needs to install to program files so it can't use click once. That being said, when I build it with click once. it works perfectly np.

However when I install it via install shield i get this exception

> The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files (x86)\King Canine\King Canine Software\CanineDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I have the SQL Server 2014 LocalDB as part of the redistrib selected and it is installed on the computer I'm testing it on.

Has anyone ever had this issue before or have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you posted, it can mean either of the following:

**A database with the same name exists**
this means that the database you are trying to attach already exist on the database.

**specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share**
you can try to check if the folder of the **.mdf** file you are trying to attach has enough folder access rights, you can see this on the folder's properties, in the security section.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the connection string like this:

   ```
   string connectionStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=CanineDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security = True";
   ```
2. Make a T-SQL query for make Database in server:

   ```
   USE [master]
   GO

   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'CanineDatabase.mdf')
     BEGIN  
     EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'CanineDatabase.mdf',   
       @filename1 =   'C:\Program Files (x86)\King Canine\King Canine Software\CanineDatabase.mdf',   
       @filename2 =   'C:\Program Files (x86)\King Canine\King Canine Software\CanineDatabase_log.ldf';
     END 
     GO
   ```